# how to add mean of 2D array as list elements in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, k-means

```
clus = np.asarray(clus)
cens[0] = np.mean(clus, axis=0, dtype=np.float32)
```

#

clus1, clus2, clus3 are 2D arrays of coordinates.
I think it can calculate the mean of x-axis and y-axis separately by calling numpy.mean and set axis to 0, then it returns me [x,y].
(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)

but I failed and got the error below.

[TypeError: cannot preform reduce with flexible type][1]

How can I fix it? Or what does the error mean?

thanks

#

update 2017.9.9

clus1,2,3 are lists read from csv file like this

```
98,157
101,130
206,218
158,162
189,237
212,186
63,35
196,188
185,176
```

and read like this

```
with open('clus_1.csv', 'rb') as c1:
    rc1 = csv.reader(c1)
    list_c1 = list(rc1)

clus.append(list_c1)
```

Comment: Could you provide a dummy example of what contains clus1, clus2 or clus3 ? It seems that there's a problem with the type they contain

Comment: updated the information, thanks

Comment: You should distill this code to a single, straight-through executable script which we can just copy/paste and run.  And remove all the triple copies of everything if you can reproduce the problem with a single array.

Comment: distilled. and i found out the error is that what's i read from csv files are strings not ints

Answer (score 0):

What I read from csv files are not ints but strings.
add codes below can solve it

```
clus = clus.astype(np.float32)
```